# Execute a range of commands from history

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, history

I am using Ubuntu and I'd like to repeat a bunch of commands I performed. I tried something like

```
for i in $(seq 2006 2013); do \!$i; done;
```

but failed, since shell tries to execute a command '!2006'.

```
man history
```

also didn't reveal to me how to repeat a range of commands.

Comment: cannot find anything similar in [Event designators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html)

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is all I found too, in man history.

Comment: Is the shell `bash` (or `ksh`)?  Does `fc -e - 2006 2013` not work?

Comment: It should be bash. It executes only 2006 ...

Comment: That's curious; you seem to be right, even though `fc 2006 2013` will give you 8 command lines to edit and then execute whatever commands you leave in the file after exiting the editor. OK; since `bash` is playing tricks with us, we'll have to play tricks on `bash`.  Tell `bash` to use `:` as the editor: `fc -e : 2006 2013`.

Comment: Yes, this works. I also managed to use fc -s $i in the loop. I didn't know fc. Thanks for the hint. If you create an answer out of you comment, I will vote for it, of course. :-)

Comment: Yes that's right, I was also able to make this work: `for i in {2006..2013}; do fc -s $i; done` But @JonathanLeffler: trick of fooling BASH was also great using `fc -e :` :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using `bash` (or `ksh`), the [`fc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-History-Builtins) built-in allows you to manipulate history in various ways.

```
fc -l                   # list recent history.
fc -l      2006 2013    # list commands 2006..2013
fc         2006 2013    # launch editor with commands 2006..2013; executes what you save
fc -e pico 2006 2013    # launches the editor pico on command 2006..2013
fc -e -    2006 2013    # Suppresses the 'edit' phase (but only executes the first listed command)
fc -e :    2006 2013    # Launches the ':' command (a shell built-in) as the editor
```

The classic technique in `ksh` is to use an alias `alias r='fc -e -'`, but because of the behaviour of `bash`, it is necessary to twist its arm a little harder and use `alias r='fc -e :'` instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
for i in $(seq 2006 2013); do \!$i; done;
```

in your code, you may think ! is like ! in bash command line,  but here "!" with the "$i" become a string like string command "!2006, !2007 ... !2013" but actually there is no command named "!2006"  "!2006" in whole is a command name.

in **Bash ! is a event designator**. when you use !2006. 
it is explained as "reference to command 2006" but not use command "!2006".

! is always left to right execute command.

for more information please visit http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators

I try the following way to get the same result:

```
for i in $(seq 2006 2013); do  fc -e - $i; done;
```